# Docker and Laravel environment variables over .env file

Tags: laravel, postgresql, docker, sqlite, environment-variables

I use sqlite connection in my .env file and override that in the `environment` section of the docker-compose file:

```
environment:
      - DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
      - DB_HOST=db
```

So when I run `php artisan migrate` in my `command` section it works fine and run migrations in the Postgres, but when I start with `php artisan serve` it connects to the sqlite db, having save environment variables. Looks like a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Snippet is the following:

```
    command: bash -c "php artisan key:generate && php artisan migrate --force --seed && php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0"
ports: 
  - 8000:8000
environment:
  - DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
  - DB_HOST=db
```